# Jmeter Oauth2 access token request fails with response code 401

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, authorization, performance-testing

Long story short, I'm trying to get guest's token, but receive 401 response code and I'm not quite sure, what I'm doing wrong.

[image: HTTP Request]

[image]
JSR223 PreProcessor code:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

byte[] encodedUsernamePassword = Base64.encodeBase64("user_pass".getBytes());
vars.put("auth",new String(encodedUsernamePassword));
```

[image]

[image]

Response data:

```
Response code:401
Response message:Unauthorized
```

Request documentation
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, where was the problem: I had to send grant_type as parameter without scope
[image]